# 16.04 to 16.04.2 System is Running in Low Graphics Mode

Tags: 16.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm upgrading my T460s Skylake from 16.04 to 16.04.2, and I'm running into this modal window stating that the system is running in low graphics mode. I've already tried running update/upgrade in a tty1 session. Also, tried reinstalling gdm and then lightdm. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its seems it was easier than i expected because I missed a step. I followed this article first before doing any kind of research.

[OmgUbuntu Article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/download-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Edit: I may also expand on this... to get to the tty1 session to run these commands press CTRL+ALT+F1 and then login once you get to that modal window.